# Eclipse & maven output directories

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I'm using eclipse juno & maven 2.2.1.

Is there a simple way for separating eclipse output folder with the one of maven ?
So I'd like to have eclipse building in the target directory and maven in the target-maven directory.

I tried using

```
 <directory>target-maven</directory>
```

in the pom.xml.

It's working fine if I do that after creating the project.
But when recovering the project from svn (without .classpath .target ...   only src folder) followed by eclipse:eclipse, everything is building in target-maven.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [different profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for this. Create a profile `mvn-eclipse` for Eclipse and `mvn-cmd` for the command line where you specify different target directories. You need to activate the profiles in the Eclipse Launch Configurations (select `Run as -> Maven Build ...` and theres the `Profiles` field) or you may [create two different `settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html). In one you specify

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mvn-eclipse</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

and in the other

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mvn-cmd</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

You should name the settings file that contain `mvn-cmd` as an active profile `settings.xml`, so that you don't have to make any changes when using maven on the command line. In Eclipse you can specify the settings via `Preferences -> Maven -> User settings`.

However I don't recommend this, since you may run into trouble with both output folders running out of sync. So be sure to have a good reason for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  But I don't know how to do that.  My good reason is that the project have a lot of test cases and I don't want to execute them each time i build the project.  So i use -Dmaven.test.skip=true.  But if i do a clean the test classes are cleaned but not rebuilded.  So in eclipse if i want to run a simple test i have to edit the class, save, and then run as.

Comment: I don't think that your reason is a good one. We once went a similiar path an that lead to a project which was completely disfunctional after some time, because everyone excluded its tests from running. If your tests are taking too much time you are probably running into another problem. When just normally building in eclipse those tests shouldn't be executed and you shouldn't have a problem with them.

Comment: For me, the reason is developing Atlassian Jira plugins. Jira SDK runs a development server out of the target directory. If I let Eclipse build automatically, Eclipse's action will mess with the running server instance. But if Eclipse don't build automatically, then I lose a lot of context help. So I must make Eclipse and Jira SDK use different output directoies while sharing the same pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of in response to the first answer, here is a legitimate reason to have separate output folders for Maven and Eclipse:

I'm trying to work on a rather large Maven-based project (200+ subprojects) involving the latest Scala (2.13), which is not supported in Eclipse. [Scala-IDE is effectively dead at 2.12](https://gitter.im/scala-ide/scala-ide?at=5d78f6626e889c4bbdd9c4ca). Without it, doing a clean build in Eclipse will delete the Maven-compiled Scala classes and break everything oh so thoroughly. I'm not sure if I need to mention that m2e is unusable, too.

So it all ended with a few lines of perl to fix my workspace. Believe me, I have tried a lot of other approaches. This solution still requires me to supply the compiled Scala classes to Eclipse in another scripted step, but that's not really an issue at this point.

This solution will not change Maven's, but Eclipse's output folders by adjusting `.classpath` files generated by `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Change the target folder in the call to `setAttribute(...)` to your liking and run the script in the project root.

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use XML::XPath;

my $files = [];
find_files( '.', '^\.classpath$', $files );

for my $file ( @$files ) {
    my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => $file );

    $xp->find( '/classpath/classpathentry[@kind="output"]' )
       ->[0]
       ->setAttribute( 'path', 'target-eclipse' );

    open my $ofh, '>', $file or die 'Cannot open for writing: '.$file;
    print $ofh $xp->getNodeAsXML;
    close $ofh;
}

sub find_files {
    my ( $path, $mask, $hits ) = @_;
    opendir my $dh, $path or die 'Cannot open path: '.$path;
    for my $entry ( grep { ! /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir $dh ) {
        my $fullpath = $path.'/'.$entry;
        if ( -d $fullpath ) {
            find_files( $fullpath, $mask, $hits );
        } elsif ( $entry=~/$mask/ ) {
            push @$hits, $fullpath;
        }
    }
    closedir $dh;
}
```

**Update:** If you don't mind regenerating *all* of Eclipse's files (which will wipe any other custom settings you might have), you can simply do this:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DoutputDirectory=target-eclipse
```